# How can I have figure serial numbers on the top left corner and a caption that is not centering?

Tags: floats, subfloats

Like this
[image]

I have tried \sidesubfloat[] to place the serial numbers on the top left corner, but the caption will be centered.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Which document class do you employ? Do you employ the `subcaption` or the `subfig` package?

Comment: @Mico sorry for the unclarity.  I use revtex4-2 and do not employ those packages.

Comment: If this is for publication, do not modify the caption.  If these plots are generated by pgfplots, you can add nodes containing (A) and (B) anywhere.

Comment: @John Kormylo Thanks for your advices!